# "have their own beliefs" VS "have their own belief"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Many ethnic groups have their own religious **beliefs** that are associated with unique traditions and styles in architecture, clothing, rituals, and diet.
> 2. Many ethnic groups have their own religious **belief** that is associated with a unique tradition and style in architecture, clothing, rituals, and diet.

In such case, which form of word shoule I go for?

Comment: I suppose any religion has a group of beliefs they follow, so I would use "beliefs".  In your specific case, "styles in architecture, clothing, rituals, and diet." must be several styles. But it would be helpful if you add to your question why you think one or the other might be OK.

Comment: It's *possible* that many ethnic groups have only a *single* religious belief that's associated with all of those things—but it's pretty unlikely. In any reasonable interpretation of the meaning here, I'd say it should be the plural. Alternatively, you could have it read *at least one religious belief that is* . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford Your comment would make a great answer!

Comment: @JasonBassford how about i change 'religious belief' to 'religion', then will still single form be the best?
Many ethnic groups have their own religion(religions) that is(are) associated with a unique tradition and style in architecture, clothing, rituals, and diet.

Comment: @MikePhilip That would end up being quite a different question. In that case, the singular seems better—but the sentence should be rephrased to switch the positions of *unique* and *their own*. So: *Many ethnic groups (have / follow) a unique religion that is associated with their own tradition . . .*

Answer (score 1):

"Beliefs" speaks to their beliefs / religion as a whole. "Belief" signifies a single position.

"A supports position Y, but I have my own belief."
"A is a follower of religion X, but I have my own beliefs."

In your example, you should go with beliefs. If you were talking about a specific issue, then use the singular: "Each ethnic group has its own belief about the proper color of the wedding dress."